# Why this div is not going under the other div

Tags: html, css

im new with the web dev thing and im trying to make slideshow, now i wanna put another div under the slideshow that has a paragraph but when i try to do it the paragraph goes over the slideshow.
this picture will explain my problem better i guess.. what i want is the paragraph stay under the slideshow

HTML :

```
<nav class="nav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48" fill="#FFD60A" class="bi bi-camera-fill"
                viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M10.5 8.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 1-5 0 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 5 0z" />
                <path
                    d="M2 4a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v6a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V6a2 2 0 0 0-2-2h-1.172a2 2 0 0 1-1.414-.586l-.828-.828A2 2 0 0 0 9.172 2H6.828a2 2 0 0 0-1.414.586l-.828.828A2 2 0 0 1 3.172 4H2zm.5 2a.5.5 0 1 1 0-1 .5.5 0 0 1 0 1zm9 2.5a3.5 3.5 0 1 1-7 0 3.5 3.5 0 0 1 7 0z" />
            </svg>
            <h1 class="name">Zon Photography</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <a href="" class="is-active">HOME</a>
            <a href="#PACKAGES">PACKAGES</a>
            <a href="">PHOTOS</a>
            <a href="">ABOUT</a>
            <a href="">CONTACT US</a>
        </div>
        <button class="humberger">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="Slider">
    <div class="myslider fade">
        <img id="imgslid" src="/Images/1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="myslider fade">
        <img id="imgslid" src="/Images/2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="myslider fade">
        <img id="imgslid" src="/Images/3.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="myslider fade">
        <img id="imgslid" src="/Images/4.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="myslider fade">
        <img id="imgslid" src="/Images/5.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

</div>
<div class="packcontainer">
    <p> My paragraph goes here</p>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.container{
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

nav{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    padding: 16px 32px;
}
/* Slide Show Container */
.slider{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #003566;
}
/* Hide the images by default*/
.myslider{
    max-height: 255px;
    display: none;
    
}
/* Fading animation */
.fade {
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
  }
  
  @keyframes fade {
   from {opacity: 0,4}
    to {opacity: 1}
  }
  /* LOGO */ 
svg{
    margin-top: 20px;
}
/* ZON PHOTOGRAPHY */
.name{
    display: none;
    float: right;
    color: #FFC300;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}

/* Humberger Container */ 
.humberger{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    user-select: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;

}
/* Humberger Lines */
.humberger span{
    display: block;
    width: 33px;
    height: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFC300 ;
    border-radius: 6px;
    z-index: 1;

    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transition: 0.4s;

}
/* Humberger Transofrmation */
.humberger:hover span:nth-child(2){
        transform: translateX(10px);
        background-color: #003566;
}
.humberger.is-active span:nth-child(1){
    transform: translate(0px, -2px) rotate(45deg);
}
.humberger.is-active span:nth-child(3){
    transform: translate(-3px, 3px) rotate(-45deg);
}
.humberger.is-active span:nth-child(2){
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(15px);
}

.humberger.is-active:hover span{
    background-color: #0862b8;
}
/* NAV MENU LIST */
.menu{
    display: none;
    flex: auto;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
}
.menu a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.4s;  
}

 .menu a:hover{
    color:#FFC300;
}
/* NAV MENU TRANSFORMATION */
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .humberger{
        display: none;
    }
    .menu{
        display: flex;
    }
    .name{
        display: flex;
    }
    #slider ul li img{
        width: 100%
      }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using `position: absolute` on `nav` tag which is creating the issue.
You should change it to `relative`.

Comment: how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the position to relative. That will probably solve the problem.

Comment: Actually, i found the issue.. it was the height of the pictures, when i put a specific height the paragraph went exactly where i wanted it to be. Thank you for replies !